# The data that comes from an API end point is undefined in the child component in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Good day to all!
I have this situation: I use Apollo client to get data from a GraphQL API endpoint in the parent class component in React. I pass this data to the child class component. The first time everything works fine but after a page refresh the data in the child component becomes undefined and the app crashes.

Here is the representation of the situation:

The ParentComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";
import {graphql} from 'react-apollo';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'

const getProducts = gql`
{
    category {
        products {
            id
            name
            gallery   
           
         } 
            
     }
 }
 `

 class ParentComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          products: []
        }
   }

   componentDidMount() {
       setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            products: [...this.props.data.category.products]
        })
        
      }, 1000)
   }

    render () {
     let products = this.state.products;

      return (
         <div><ChildComponent  theProducts = {products}/></div>   
   
      )


   }

}

export default graphql(getProducts)(ParentComponent);
```

The ChildComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'



 class ChildComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          products: this.props.theProducts
        }
   }

   

    render () {
     let item = this.state.products.find(each => each.id === id);

      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
                <li>{item.name}</li>
                <li><img src= {item.gallery[0]} alt="product"></img></li>
           </ul>
        </div>   
   
      )


   }

}

export default ChildComponent;
```

So, when the app starts everything seems to work fine. But if I refresh the page it throws an error and says that name is undefined, gallery is undefined. It is clear that the data is not coming through to the ChildComponent. Is there a way to make sure that the data comes in at any time?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use `theProducts` in the `ChildComponent` but you pass `theProduct` from `ParentComponent` . And state `product` also has the same error. Just update to `theProducts` and  `product`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, but they are just typos I made while creating a simplified version of my situation. They have been corrected.